# How to make a http request in Outlook add-ins?

Tags: outlook, fetch, office-js, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins

I want to make a request from Outlook Add-ins (built with React) to some APIS using fetch or axios

Here are some urls:

- https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1
- https://api.github.com/users/1
- localhost

Add-in in web version works just fine, but in my Outlook 2016 Desktop doesn't work.
Testing on my Express server, Outlook 2016 Desktop event didn't fire a request

I follow these steps:

- manifest.xml

```
<AppDomains>
    <AppDomain>https://www.contoso.com</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://api.github.com/users</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>http://localhost:3001</AppDomain>
    <AppDomain>https://localhost:3001</AppDomain>
</AppDomains>
```

- Test.tsx

```js
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Test = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // axios.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users/1").then((res) => setUser(res.data));
    // axios.get("http://localhost:3001/my-test").then((res) => setUser(res.data));
  }, []);
  return <div>user: {user && user.name}</div>;
};

export default Test;
```

Using xhr works but I don't know why

```
 var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.addEventListener("readystatechange", function () {
      if (this.readyState === 4) {
        setUser(JSON.parse(this.responseText));
      }
    });

    xhr.open("GET", "http://localhost:3001/my-test");
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");

    xhr.send();
```

There is also a random issue with loading css file (most of the time happens)

```
<link href="taskpane.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
```

included in header of taskpane.html also

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The same-origin policy enforced by the browser prevents a script loaded from one domain from getting or manipulating properties of a webpage from another domain. This means that, by default, the domain of a requested URL must be the same as the domain of the current webpage. For example, this policy will prevent a webpage in one domain from making request web-service calls to a domain other than the one where it is hosted.

Because Office Add-ins are hosted in a browser control, the same-origin policy applies to script running in their web pages as well.

Read about possible workarounds in the [Addressing same-origin policy limitations in Office Add-ins](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/addressing-same-origin-policy-limitations) article.

Comment: This link is useful for me